# Python Nested Dictionary

Tags: python

I need to find the month which has the most number of people on any day. The code I wrote just looks for the most amount of days instead of how many people have the birthday on that day

```
def total_days(birthdays):
    '''
    >>> total_days( {"Jan": {2: ["Ben"], 3: ["Sarah"], 6: ["Rob"]}, 
    "Feb": {1: ["Jimmy", "Timmmy"], 30: ["Sam", "Tony"]}})

    'Feb'

    '''
    total = 0
    month = ''
    for i in birthdays:
        new = len(birthdays[i])
        if new > total:
            total = new
            month = i
    return month
```

This code returns Jan because in January there are 3 dates while Feb has 2 but I need the month with the most amount of people  which should be Feb

Thanks

Comment: One easy solution would be to use a nested `for` loop.

Comment: i figured but i am not sure how to make it work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to go one `for` loop deeper. Your code is perfect, except immediately after your first for loop, add:

```
for j in birthdays[i]:
    {rest of your code here}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will store the result in `busiest_month`.

```
busiest_month = None
busiest_day_overall = None, 0
for month in birthdays:
    busiest_day_in_month = max([(day, len(people)) for day, people in birthdays[month].items()])
    if busiest_day_in_month[1] > busiest_day_overall[1]:
        busiest_month = month
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
from collections import Counter
birthdays = {"Jan": {2: ["Ben"], 3: ["Sarah"], 6: ["Rob"]}, 
             "Feb": {1: ["Jimmy", "Timmmy"], 30: ["Sam", "Tony"]}}

Counter({month: sum(len(names) for names in dates.values()) for (month, dates) in birthdays.items()}).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

(Well, ok, technically there are a few lines in there)

It uses dictionary and list comprehensions (dictionary comprehensions means this will only work in Python 2.7+). Essentially, it's flattening the list of dates/names down to a single value - the number of names attached to a date, then summing those per month. [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.Counter) is then used to find the highest scored element.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
def total_days(birthdays):
    total = 0
    month = ''
    for i,j in birthdays.viewitems():
       new =j.keys()
       new.sort()
       if total < new[-1]:
            total = new[-1]
            month = i
    return month
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 birthdays={"Jan": {2: ["Ben"], 3: ["Sarah"], 6: ["Rob"]},
          "Feb": {1: ["Jimmy", "Timmmy"], 30: ["Sam", "Tony"]}}
yourData=[(mon,max([len(p) for d,p in day.iteritems()])) for mon,day in birthdays.iteritems()]
print [i[0] for i in yourData if i[1]==max(map(lambda x: x[1], yourData))][0]
```